# How to change type of variable from Future<Uin8List> to Uint8List in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, dart, variables, uint8list

```
  static Future<dynamic> variance_of_laplacian(Uint8List image){
    return ImgProc.laplacian(image, 64);
  }

  static Future<Bool> isBlur(Uint8List byteData) {
    Future<Uint8List> gray = ImgProc.cvtColor(byteData, colorBGR2GRAY);

    
    Future<dynamic> fm = variance_of_laplacian(gray);
  }
```

There is an error in last line when I pass gray to `variance_of_laplacian` function because both have different variable type i.e. `Future<Uint8List>` and `Uint8List`. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use await to resolve and get the value from the future.

```
static Future<Bool> isBlur(Uint8List byteData) async {
    Uint8List gray = await ImgProc.cvtColor(byteData, colorBGR2GRAY);

    
    Future<dynamic> fm = variance_of_laplacian(gray);
  }
```